# What set did this assembly come from?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

What set did this assembly come from?

[image]

Any ideas? I'm inclined to think it's come from a Star Wars set.

Comment: Welcome back to Bricks SE.  Are you looking for the set this assembly was part of?  Or do you want the 11 individual pieces identified?

Comment: The set it was part of please. Tall ask I know!

Answer (score 9):

I think I found it:

SW911617-1: Palpatine's Shuttle

it was apparently included in a Star Wars comic magazine in November 2016

[image]

How did I do it ?

I'm the author of `pyrebrickable` (Github page [here](http://github.com/rienafairefr/pyrebrickable)), and by installing the python package `rebrickable-data` we can explore the rebrickable database directly (query it with SQL). Rebrickable contains a seemingly exhaustive set inventories with parts colors etc. In that case, I looked at 3 distinctive parts in your picture:

```
2540 # Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handle on Side - Free Ends
# thought it was white at first but it is in fact light bluish gray

60471 # Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 2 Fingers on Side
# in black

3023 # Plate 1 X 2
# in trans-clear
```

By searching in the database for sets that contain at least one of all these parts, I could narrow down to a handful of sets, and in it was that Palpatine shuttle from which we can easily recognize a part of the main ship body

Comment: Nice find, and a handy tool! Thanks for sharing that :)

Comment: @GemmaMarie if it's a match then why not accept